# How can I input the formula and get the result?

Tags: python

What I want to do is to input a formula, like 1+1, and print: The Answer of question n is : (The answer of the formula). For 1+1, it should print: The Answer of Question 1 is: 2
But what I get is, when I input 1+1, it prints: The Answer of Question 1 is: '1+1'

```
def prefix():
    typein=int(input("How many questions do you want to ask:"))
    number=1
    while number<typein+1:
        a=input("Question %r you want to ask"%(number))
        print(a)
        print("The Answer of Question %r is: %r" %(number,a))
        number+=1
prefix()
```

When I add

```
print(a)
```

after

```
a=input("Question %r you want to ask"%(number))
```

It shows that a is 1+1, not 2.
So how can I let a become the answer of the formula but not the formula itself?

--------------------------Edit-----------------------

It asks people to input an int ,and some formulas. There is no problem for us to input an int for the first part of the code. But for the second part of the code, which asks as to input the formula, it comes wrong.

Comment: Which all operators would you like to consider?

Comment: What do you input on those lines?

Comment: Hint: eval('1+1') returns 2. This should work for the most basic  expressions like: `<num1><operator><num2>`.

Comment: If I run your code and put `typein`  as `1`, I get the following output `The Answer of Question 1 is: '1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers.I know what happened right now, just like the question:
[Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

So I just have to add an eval()

```
def prefix():
typein=int(input("How many questions do you want to ask:"))
number=1
while number<typein+1:
    a=eval(input("Question %r you want to ask"%(number)))
    print("The Answer of Question %r is: %r" %(number,a))
    number+=1
prefix()
```

It works!
[image]

Comment: The answers to the duplicate questions make it very clear: `eval` is evil. They recommend **not** to use it, and give many better, safer alternatives.